# EJB Injection fails in managedbean (Websphere 8)

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, managed-bean, code-injection

i have a strange problem, that i cant explain.

I have some classes in a package **com.ejb.logic.user**.
All these classes have the following structure:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "Classname")
@LocalBean
public Classname {
```

And some of it are used in some managedBean like this:

```
@EJB
private Classname classname;
```

**Now my problem:**
On Glassfish it works without problems. There is allright. But when i deploy the application in websphere i get an exception. BUT when i rename some classes or the package it works, too. I cant explain it and i found nothing about this behavior.

**Using**: EJB 3.1 and Websphere 8. And i have a EAR- File with a WAR(ManagedBeans) and a JAR(EJB's)

**Exception**: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The
com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory
factory encountered a problem getting the object instance for
the Reference:"package/classname" binding object.

Comment: This sounds like a product issue.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.  If you can provide a self-contained testcase, that would be ideal.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have found the problem. The annotation scanning from websphere fails in some cases, it didnt find some @stateless beans and dont merge it to the "xml-jar_merged" in my ejb modul ...when i add a own xml-jar and add the missing classes it works. I try to make a simple testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a reference:

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:comp/env/ejb/.....")
```